# Data structure/Algorithm to manage non-overlapping ranges of values?

Tags: json, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, bitvector

I'm working on a system that has 10's of thousands of flags for a user. The flags are all sequential in number, 0 through X, whatever X ends up being. X is expected to grow over time. And we're expecting to have lots and lots of users as well.

Our primary concerns are:

1. Being able to quickly test whether the user has set any given flag.
2. Being able to quickly set a flag.
3. Being able to optimize the data storage to as small a size as possible.

With 10k flags, we're looking at around 1k of data per user, in memory, if we use a bit vector. Which might be too much. And to make matters worse, this is in Javascript, being stored in a document database serialized as JSON, which means that we have several storage options, none of them which I particularly like.

1. Store flags as the JSON output of the Uint32Array object. Looks like: `"{"0":10,"1":4294967295}"`. Unfortunately needs an average of 17 bytes per 4 bytes stored as the flags approach their filled state, which is over 4x the memory, and leads to about 5k of memory when serialized. This is not ideal.
2. Perform our own serialization of the JSON, using base64 to avoid the bloated sizes of the numbers-as-strings approach. Unfortunately that adds an extra processing step to the JSON input/output phases which complicates things because now we have to modify our data during the process and will slow everything down.

So... putting aside the bitvector idea for a bit. I was wondering if there's possibly a better approach. I considered using an "array of ranges", something like:

```
[{"m":0,"x":100},{"m":102},{"m":108,"x":204}]
```

We can make a few assumptions about the data in this system, which is what led me to this approach:

1. Flags are never un-set. Once it's set, it will remain set.
2. Flags are generally clustered. If flag X is set, there's a huge probability that X-1 and X+1 will be set as well.
3. Flags will generally be set at increasing index values. If Flag X is being set, then X-1 is more likely to be set than X+1, and X+1 is likely to be set fairly soon afterwards.

So because of these conditions, I think storing an array of range objects might be the optimal solution. That way, over time, the user's flags eventually condense down into one large range entry. The optimal case is of course:

```
[{"m":0,"x":10000}]
```

The worst case scenario, of course, is if they somehow manage to find themselves in a state where they set every other flag.

```
[{"m":0},{"m":2},{"m":4},{"m":6},{"m":8},{"m":10}...{"m":10000}]
```

That would be bad. Far worse than the bitvector solution, I think. But we're pretty confident that won't happen.

So, as to the ability to quickly decide if a flag is set; that's simply an O(logn) binary search (since the array will be sorted); just find the range object closest to your number, check to see if your number is in that range, and return.

Insertions are more tricky. It'll still be a binary search, but now we're modifying the array.

1. one adjacent sibling insert: optimal scenario. We find a range where the min or max is one off from the number we're inserting, and simply decrement or increment the value on the current range.  O(1)
2. No adjacent siblings insert: simply insert a new node with the min set. O(n), because we'll be moving everything after it in the array downwards.
3. Two adjacent siblings insert: Change the max to the max value of the right sibling range, delete the right sibling range from the array and shift everything after it to the left. O(n).

So cases 2+3 have me wondering if I shouldn't try to use some sort of balanced binary search tree for this. A Red-Black tree, for example.

Is that worth the bother? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: What is the average number of flags set per user in your system? And what kind of distribution is that?

Comment: What's the main bottleneck/concern here? Is it storage/serialization? Read time? Insertion time?

Comment: It's difficult to say at the moment since it's still in design. But basically we're recording "areas" the users have been to. The users will start at the lowest indices and grow upwards. As the system expands more and more indices are added as well, and so users will generally be progressing along with the expansion of the system.

There will be gaps as they miss things. They can always go back and revisit them.

Comment: I'd rank the storage issue as the primary concern. Serialization is a theoretical issue at the moment; I'm not entirely sure if that'll turn out to be an issue. Read time isn't a concern. Insertion time probably isn't either, realistically speaking, since we're almost always going to be inserting near the end of the array.

Comment: In my opinion, especially if you assume almost all of the inserts will be near the end of the array, any kind of balanced structures if an overkill. First you face this problem of serialization-deserialization. Which already does not improve anything in terms of performance because such structures are usually kept in memory during their usage. And in terms of storage it also doesn't save a byte.

Comment: Another approach would be to hash some "area" sets that are common across all users, say, many users visit areas 1-20, 23 and 25-60, then create such an entry that corresponds to these values and use just entry id instead of full description. Such approach works if you have data repetition, but I am not sure if it's the case. Once in a while it makes sense to rebuild such indices with new mostly used ones.

Comment: If you have to serialize to JSON then I think the segments approach would be less sufficient in case of more or less random distribution than plain approach of saving bit masks.